# Displays the results of data subtraction operations from the database only on the ASP.NET MVC page

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database

I want to show subtraction of data taken from the database and displayed only in page views. As in the source code, I want to subtraction the amount of quota with the amount used that will equal to the remaining value. The remaining values will be displayed on the page view, without having to save the results in the database. I am using ASP.NET MVC with a MySQL database. Thank You.

```
 @model IEnumerable<Train.Models.Ticket>
 ...
    @foreach (var item in Model){
          <tr>                   
           <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Quota)</td>
           <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Used)</td>
           <!-- <td>Quota - Used = ?</td> -->
          </tr>
         }
```

Comment: You can do simply <td>@(item.Quota - item.Used)</td>

Comment: @Dharmeshsharma put that in the answer so they could mark this as answered/closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do simply

```
<td>@(item.Quota - item.Used)</td>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
<td>Remaining value=item.Quota-item.Used</td>
```

Comment: Dear @Aniee in Razor you can not directly use C# syntax so whenever you want to use C# syntax in Razor or view page then you have to use @ or @() or @{} so razor can understand this is C# syntax.

Answer (score 0):

`<td>@(item.Quota - item.Used)</td>`

Comment: Adding a description helps better understand the answer, no matter how small.